# How to write Euler's e with its special font

Tags: fonts, formatting, euler

I have searched but its surprisingly difficult to find, I want an e that looks like this one instead of the default e:
[image]

Comment: Is `$e$` what you want?

Comment: $e$ is similar to it but I think I've seen there was an alternate like $l$ and $\ell$ but with this e

Comment: `$\mathcal{e}$` maybe? A recommendation: search here, sometimes it works https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Do I require some package? When I use this it gives me some strange upside down inverted L symbol instead.

Comment: Normally, as it is a constant, it should be upright, obtained with this code `\mathrm{e}`.

Comment: There has never been a special symbol for the Bernoulli constant (I've never understood why it is named after Euler, when it was discovered by Jacob Bernoulli; sometimes it's even called Napier's number, but Napier knew nothing *at all* about it). It's simply an “e” in the current mathematical font; mathematicians usually typeset it in italics, some people, usually not mathematicians, claim it should be upright. Don't worry, use “e” and go on.

Comment: I'm a mathematician and, in spite of what @egreg says, since I don't italicize $1$, $2$, or other constants, I don't italicize $\mathrm{e}$, either.  I do wish AMS-LaTeX made it easier to typeset an upright pi.

Comment: @EricTowers The AMS has long ago issued the fonts for `amssymb` where they added several symbol they felt useful for typesetting mathematics. There is no upright pi there, which simply means that they aren't using it. I'm not going to question whether the AMS practice is good or not: but it's an authoritative source anyhow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is simply an "e" in a Times clone. Your image seems to have been produced with `mathptmx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\[
e \equiv \lim_{n\to\infty} \biggl( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \biggr)^n = 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572\hdots
\]
\end{document}
```

Note however that `mathptmx` is obsolete; if you want to use a Times clone you should use [`newtx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) instead.

Answer (score 13):

I’m going to give some alternatives, if you don’t mind.  You already got a good answer to the question of which *e* that is.

There is a codepoint for “Euler’s constant” defined in Unicode, ℇ (U+2107), which is `\Eulerconst` in some packages.  It’s not widely-used, and the consensus is that most fonts’ glyphs for it are ugly.

On the other hand, `\mathrm{e}` is nearly always identical to e from the plain text font.  This conforms to the convention of typesetting constants upright and variables in italic.  (Before egreg shows up here to point it out, I will mention that not all mathematicians agree with that.)  It would be possible for an OpenType math font to use its ASCII codepoints for upright math symbols that are not copied from the text font, or for a legacy math font to supply a `\mathrm` alphabet different from the text font, but as of 2020, no math fonts do so.

So I personally like to patch in upright math constants from a different upright font.  One of my favorite combinations is Hermann Zapf’s Palatino and AMS Euler.  It’s not the style you were asking about, but here is a sample of Euler’s identities, typeset with free clones of Euler and Palatino.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and [the OpenType font Neo Euler](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf).

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[
  Scale=1.0,
  Ligatures={Common, Discretionary, TeX}]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak},
              script-features={},
              sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}
\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Asana / Pagella / Euler sample]

If you need a matching sans-serif font, you can use Zapf’s Optima (or its clone URW Classico, on CTAN but with a restrictive license).  An excellent Humanist monospace font is Inconsolata.

You can substitute basically any fonts of your choice here.  As another example, an upright companion for Computer Modern might be

```
\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}

\setmathfont{CMU Serif Upright Italic}[
  range=up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
  Scale=MatchLowercase ]
```

[image: New Computer Modern / CMU Serif Upright Italic sample]

It is also possible to do something similar in legacy PDFTeX, but not nearly as standardized.  Here is the Euler and Palatino example with the Type 1 versions of the fonts:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tgpagella, newpxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{euler}{U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{euler}{bold}{U}{zeur}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upe}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"65}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upi}{\mathalpha}{euler}{"69}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: newpx / pagella / euler sample]

Matching an upright font to other math fonts would need to be done on a case-by-case basis, and quickly gets complicated.  For Computer Modern, you might take the Latin letters from the upright italic style, `{T1}{cmr}{m}{ui}`, Greek lowercase letters from `{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}`, and Greek uppercase letters from either OT1 or LGR.

Comment: Huh, I would expect a unicode character for "Euler's constant" to refer to the Euler-Mascheroni constant, but I just double checked and the symbol for that is $γ$, not $ε$. (okay I don't know how to insert mathjax on this SE)

Comment: @Hearth Ironically, TeX.SX does not let you use `$` markup. You can, however, type the Unicode letter-like symbols.

Comment: @Hearth In any case, the Unicode Consortium’s name for U+2107 is “EULER CONSTANT.”

Answer (score 7):

Just be sure to load a Times Roman text and math font and you're all set: \textit{e}, $e$, and $\mathit{e}$ will all generate the desired glyph. If you load the `newtxmath` math font package, `$\mathscr{e}$` may also be of interest.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone text and math font packages
\begin{document}
\textit{e} $\mathit{e}$ $e$ $\mathscr{e}$
\end{document}
```